# Jenkins: Run parameterized build triggered by a git push

Tags: jenkins

I have a parameterized Jenkins Job. I only have one choice parameter with three options. I am setting the Job to be triggered by a git push from a git project where I added a web hook. The build are successfully triggered by the git push of my project.

What I want is: When the build is triggered by the git push, I want to run the build three times, each with one of the three options.

How can I pass this parameter to my triggered build without using any other plugin?

Comment: Would creating a downstream job that you kick off 3 times from the upstream job be a solution?  For example, you would move the logic you want to run 3 times into a separate job and then just kick off that job 3 times passing in a different parameter each time.

Comment: I am not able to pass any parameters. By default, when the build is triggered, the first choice is used. I tried to add a parameter using web hook  URL http/jenkinshost/myproject?param=val2 but it still runs with the first value

Comment: Thanks for the info...  Interesting..  However, I was thinking the upstream job triggered by the git push wouldn't take any parameters..  you would define those in the jenkinsfile or as a matrix axis..    For example, if you go the jenkinsfile route, you would do something like node { build("someJob", parameterA) build("someJob", parameterB) build("someJob", parameterC) }  and if you go with the matrix route, you would use predefined axis with values of parameterA, parameterB, parameterC.